# (WIN) Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.yq9c1.mongodb.net

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

As title suggests, I am getting an error when attempting to connect to mongodb atlas.

> Error: querySrv ENOTFOUND _mongodb._tcp.cluster0.yq9c1.mongodb.net

.env

```
ATLAS_URI=mongodb+srv://<username>:<pass>@cluster0.yq9c1.mongodb.net/<db>?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config();

const server = express();
const port = 5000;

server.use(cors());
server.use(express.json());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true })
.catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB connected');
})
.catch(err => console.log(`Error: ${err}`));

const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
server.use('/user', userRouter);

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server: ${port}`);
});
```

dependencies

```
    "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.10.9",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
```

I've connected many times in the past the same way, however I am developing on Windows now (first time) and I am uncertain if I am overlooking something simple. Double checked passwords. Usernames. Database access. Network access. Running out of ideas.